# why does "exit" , causes page not to display at all, while echoing " " gets the job done?

Tags: php, exit

i am studying php, and i was wondering why does `exit;`  on line 6 causes page go all white, while using `echo " ";` on line 7 makes it work as expected.
here is the code:

```
<?php 
 if ($_POST['username']=="user" && $_POST['password']=="password") {
    header("Location: game.html");
}
else {
  //(if i write exit on this line, i get all white page)  exit;
  // (if i echo empty string the site works ok)     echo "";
} ?>


<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
    <meta charset="UTF-8">
    <title></title>
</head>
<body>

    <h3 style="text-align: center">რეგისტრაცია</h3>

    <div style="margin: 0 300px 0 300px">
    <form action="index.php" method="post">
    მომხმარებელი: <input type="text" name="username" value=""><br />
    პაროლი: <input type="password" name="password" value="" style="margin-left: 47px"><br/>
            <input type="submit" name="submit" value="შესვლა" style="margin-left: 170px">
     </form>
     </div>

</body>
```

this is the actual website by me - for learning purposes http://nikolozasatiani.com/, feel free to enjoy the game after login :D username: user  password: password

Comment: Please read about exit on the PHP manual: http://php.net/manual/en/function.exit.php It says it terminates the script

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The language construct [`exit`](http://php.net/manual/en/function.exit.php) stops the execution, i.e. everything below (in your case the HTML) never gets sent to the output buffer because PHP doesn't parse anything past that point.

However, when doing `echo " ";`, you just print a space on the page. In your example you could just omit the `else`-part as it doesn't do anything:

```
if ($_POST['username']=="user" && $_POST['password']=="password") {
    header("Location: game.html");
}
```

and actually, as only one line is executed in the if-statement, you could also omit the curly brackets if you like that syntax better. Personally I think it looks cleaner:

```
if ($_POST['username']=="user" && $_POST['password']=="password")
    header("Location: game.html");
```

Comment: does it kill the whole document? or only the first part  - the  php script?

Comment: You can think of it like a pair of scissors. If you were to read a sheet of text from the top down (which PHP does), whenever you met `exit`, you would cut the paper right there.  So everything above that would still be known to you (be output to the browser), anything below ends in the trashcan ;)

Comment: Nah, I don't think so. Someone might meet the same problem (although its **very** basic), so let's leave it on the great big internet